# Question vote count on network profile doesn't match that on question page

Tags: bug, voting, network-profile, top-questions

On my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/410264/pacoverflow), it shows the following question with 21 votes:

[image]

But when you go to [that question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/would-humans-starve-if-spiders-disappeared), it shows 22 votes:

[image]

I noticed that the count on my network profile changed from 22 to 21 about a week ago (so it's not a caching issue).  At about the same time that it changed, my [reputation on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/13812/pacoverflow?tab=reputation) showed that someone upvoted and unupvoted the question:

[image]

So it seems like the network profile picked up the unupvote event but not the upvote event.

Comment: Somebody just upvoted the question, and now the network profile shows the correct total.

Comment: Rare edge case, while a bug don't think it's high priority - think something similar was already posted.